# mongodb query continuously running

Tags: email, mongodb, centos

I have a mail archive setup and it runs the following query which does not return any results. It just runs continuously. Is there anything wrong with the following query

```
query:{ $or: [ { $or: [ { rcpt_to: /vpadmin@vp.local/i }, { to: /vpadmin@vp.local/i }, { cc: /vpadmin@vp.local/i } ] } ] }
```

Is the result meant to look like this?

```
[
    {
        "$or" : [
            {
                "rcpt_to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i
            },
            {
                "to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i
            },
            {
                "cc" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The mail archive application shows the following in the log which works and brings back results. This search is done with date

```
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.userWorkspaces ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:152 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.workspaces ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:567 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] insert enkive.searchQueries 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] insert enkive.searchResults 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.workspaces ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:567 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3]   running multiple plans
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] update enkive.workspaces  query: { _id: ObjectId('502b861ee4b04443c5db0481'), CreationDate: new Date(1345029662391), ModifiedUpdate: new Date(1346155131079), Creator: "enkive", WorkspaceName: "Default Workspace", SearchResults: [ "50334ba3e4b06e22baa0f244", "50334bbce4b06e22baa0f247", "50334be0e4b06e22baa0f24a", "5034f31fe4b06e22baa0f2e1", "503c9b73e4b002566417e868", "503cb27be4b002566417e86b", "5034f298e4b06e22baa0f2cc", "50334c72e4b06e22baa0f259", "5034f334e4b06e22baa0f2e4", "503c9b37e4b002566417e862", "503c9b62e4b002566417e865", "5035f329e4b0f6af52a5bb6c" ] } 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.searchResults ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:202 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.searchResults ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:202 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3]   running multiple plans
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] update enkive.searchResults  query: { _id: ObjectId('503cb2e8e4b002566417e870'), ExecutionTimestamp: new Date(1346155240232), ExecutedBy: "enkive", SearchResults: {}, Status: "QUEUED", SearchQueryId: "503cb2e8e4b002566417e86f", IsSaved: false } 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.emailMessages reslen:6496 nreturned:2 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] insert enkive.auditLog 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.searchResults ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:203 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3]   running multiple plans
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] update enkive.searchResults  query: { _id: ObjectId('503cb2e8e4b002566417e870'), ExecutionTimestamp: new Date(1346155240237), ExecutedBy: "enkive", SearchResults: {}, Status: "RUNNING", SearchQueryId: "503cb2e8e4b002566417e86f", IsSaved: false } 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.emailMessages ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:2226 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] insert enkive.auditLog 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] query enkive.emailMessages ntoreturn:1 idhack  reslen:4306 0ms
Tue Aug 28 13:00:40 [conn3] insert enkive.auditLog 0ms
```

@sammaya I get the following when I run what you gave me

```
> db.emailMessages.find( { $or : [ {"rcpt_to" : vpadmin@vp.local}, {"cc" : vpadmin@vp.local}, {"to" : vpadmin@vp.local} ]} );
Tue Aug 28 17:26:10 SyntaxError: missing } after property list (shell):1
```

Comment: You missed one curly bracket at the end. Add } to the end of query.

Comment: do you just want to or rcpt_to, to and cc? why did you have two or query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this normally happens is because of speed problems within the query.

You are using nested $or's with index unfriendly regexes.

Now none pre-pended regexes do not use indexes ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions ) and will force a full table scan. Nested $or clauses do not use an index either: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327 so your query is scanning what could potentially be a very very very large table.

As it is a mail archive setup I would say it could be scanning millions of documents. This is why you get no response and the query just "runs" forever.

You can try changing your schema a little to improve performance. For a start you can omit the nested $or and you could probably split out email addresses within the headers fields of  the mails to search on so you could have a query more like:

```
db.emailMessages.find( { 
    $or : [ {"rcpt_to" : vpadmin@vp.local},
            {"cc" : vpadmin@vp.local}, 
            {"to" : vpadmin@vp.local} ]
} )
```

The fields you query on here could be arrays of email addresses and this would work fine. After this you would want to setup the right indexes as @Macdiesel says:

```
db.emailMessages.ensureIndex( { rcpt_to: 1, cc: 1, to: 1 }, { background: true } );
```

I create a compound index here since MongoDB can only use one index per query.

That should not only return a response but also not kill your server and should be super performant and scalable (well mostly, could probably do with more improvements).

### Edit

Ok so some clarification.

You will need to quote your search strings like so:

```
db.emailMessages.find( { 
    $or : [ {"rcpt_to" : "vpadmin@vp.local"},
            {"cc" : "vpadmin@vp.local"}, 
            {"to" : "vpadmin@vp.local"} ]
} )
```

And since all but one of these fields can be multiple email addresses I would recommend you split `cc` and `to` into an array of email addresses like:

```
{
    _id: {},
    rcpt_to: "vpadmin@vp.local",
    cc: ["me@awesome.com", "you@kool.com"],
    to: ["another@notsokool.com"],
    message: "yo"
}
```

This is of course just an example schema and you will need to play around with it to get exactly what you want but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: @sammaya It is starting to make some sense now. Thanks. This application is enkive, opensource, which is still new and has many bugs.

Comment: @sharif Yea you'll need speach marks around your text, also you would need to change your schema a little, let me edit a sec

Comment: @sharif Ok added an edit, it should clear things up a little.

Comment: Updated query, Finally I get some results, Thank you. I hope enkive implement this

Comment: @sharif glad to have helped :)

Comment: Sharif, Why don't you submit a patch to enknive to help them fix this issue?

Comment: Macdiesel - i am not aware on how to make patches but have made them aware of this

Answer (score 2):

Lets talk about why this query is slow.

How big is your data set?

Do you have any indexes on any of these fields?

Since you have an or statement and a regex in your query it may take a while to run, especially if you have a rather large data set.

How long are you waiting before you say "never comes back?"

couldn't you rewrite the query as so?

```
db.emailMessages.find( { $or : [ {"rcpt_to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i},
                                 {"cc" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i}, 
                                 {"to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i} 
                               ] 
                        } 
                      )
```

Also maybe try adding some indexes to these fields:

```
db.emailMessages.ensureIndex( { rcpt_to: 1, cc: 1, to: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

Also you may want to look in to writing a mongo map/reduce job to do this query instead of using the query language or adding any indexes.  You will need to do a full table scan to query this data anyway, and map reduce is a much better way of handling this.

Here is a link to mongodb map/reduce:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

EDIT:

I changed the index creation per another answer as he is correct, mongo will only use one index for a query.

Comment: I go the query from an email archiving application called enkive. It is still in its early stages of development and a few features where not working like the one listed

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing brace.

```
query:{ $or: [ { $or: [ { rcpt_to: /vpadmin@vp.local/i }, { to: /vpadmin@vp.local/i }, { cc: /vpadmin@vp.local/i } ] } ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

> db.content.find({$or : [{"rcpt_to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i},{"cc" :
>   /vpadmin@vp.local/i}, {"to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i}]});

```
{$or : 
    [
        {"rcpt_to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i},
        {"cc" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i}, 
        {"to" : /vpadmin@vp.local/i}
    ]
}
```

Comment: the 1st one i don't get any results, and the second one i get the same response as I wrote above in my question

Comment: Those are the same queries. You should change the content name with your own content. What did you get as a response?

Comment: i do not get any response, does not show any results. I am searching for `vpadmin@vp.local` and I know it exists because if I search using date it finds the content